# CouchDB - Is it safe to delete the view files in mrview?

Tags: couchdb

I am working on a project using CouchDB and the partition or storage dedicated for the couchdb files reached its maximum capacity that the site fails to connect with CouchDB and produces connection errors. I know that couch is storage hungry but I never expect this soon. I have tried compacting methods such as:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:5984/dbname/_compact

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:5984/dbname/_view_cleanup
```

and,

```
localhost:5984/dbname/_compact/all_view_documents
```

The above commands only released 2GB of storage. As I searched which files in the partition consumes most of the storage, I found out that in a particular folder `/usr/local/var/lib/couchdb/.dbname/mrview` found a view file that is 144GB in size is in still there even when I used to compact all view documents.

**Note:** the compacted document file / database file is only 1.6GB, the total partition storage is 150GB

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem too.
Apparently these are files that increase when the design views are modified because the indexes are recomputed
my test was to delete the files and functionally testing my application
were re-create some of these files but with a much smaller
could assume that there is no problem in deleting and that this increase in size should not worry unless we change layout views

http://www.staticshin.com/programming/does-updating-a-design-document-in-couchdb-cause-rebuilding-of-views/